# Variable ++ in query loop php

Tags: php

There are 2 dynamic changing requiers thing in my html.they are "active" and "numbers (for example 1,2,3...)".I want write "active" into class if it is first element in query, else write only one space.Also I want write "1" into class of first element and for other elements,write like this "2,3,...".

So, for this scenerio, I wrote below code.But my plugin doesnt work like what I want.You can see how the numbers are created for this script on that link:

http://www.hekim.deniz-tasarim.site/elementor-685/

may it loads slowly, so I write echos for numbers here:

0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 for first query

1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 for second query

So, how can I solve this?

```
<?php
        $activeornot = 0;


        $teamnumber = 1;

                    $query = new \WP_Query($args);
                    if ($query->have_posts()) {
                        while ($query->have_posts()) {
                            $query->the_post();



                            if ($activeornot = 0):
                            $echo_active_or_not = "active";

                            else:
                            $echo_active_or_not = " ";
                            endif;
                            ?>



                                                <li role="presentation" class="<?php echo $echo_active_or_not; ?>"><a href="#team<?php echo $teamnumber; ?>" aria-controls="team<?php echo $teamnumber; ?>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="s1.jpg"></a></li>
                                                <?php echo $activeornot++; ?>
                                                <?php echo $teamnumber++; ?>
                            <?php } }
                    else {
                        echo "<div style=background:red> There is no available team member with current settings. </div>";
                    }
                    ?>

        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content">

            <?php
        $query = new \WP_Query($args);
        if ($query->have_posts()) {
            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();

                $activeornot = 0;
                if ($activeornot = 0):
                    $echo_active_or_not = "active";

                else:
                    $echo_active_or_not = " ";
                endif;
                $teamnumber = 1;
                ?>

                                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane <?php echo $echo_active_or_not; ?> team<?php echo $teamnumber; ?>" id="team<?php echo $teamnumber; ?>">
                                                <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                                    //something
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php echo $teamnumber++; ?>
                                            <?php echo $activeornot++; ?>
                                            <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: Why is this exact question posted under two different accounts? Delete whichever one you don't want to keep.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61742574/variable-in-query-loop) not also you?